# How to find a densest configuration of several non-overlapping unit disks?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, computational-geometry

Let us consider three non-overlapping unit disks in the plane. I'd like to find
a configuration of these disks s.t. the area of the convex hull of these disks is smallest.
This is related to the densest packing.
To this end I write down

```
NMinimize[{Evaluate[Area[ConvexHullRegion[RegionUnion[Disk[], Disk[{x1, y1}, 1],
 Disk[{x2, y2}, 1]]]]],  x1^2 + y1^2 >= 4 && x2^2 + y2^2 >= 4 && (x1 - x2)^2 +
 (y1 - y2)^2 >= 4}, {x1, y1, x2, y2}] // Timing
```

The above code produces a few warnings, for example,

> Area::reg: ConvexHullRegion[BooleanRegion[#1||#2||#3&,
> {Disk[{0,0}],Disk[{x1,y1},1],Disk[{x2,y2},1]}]] is not a correctly
> specified region.
> NMinimize::incst: NMinimize was unable to generate any initial points
> satisfying the inequality constraints
> {4-x1^2-y1^2<=0,4-(x1-x2)^2-(y1-y2)^2<=0,4-x2^2-y2^2<=0}.
> The initial region specified may not contain any feasible points.
> Changing the initial region or specifying explicit initial points
> may provide a better solution.

and

> `{1280.42, {10.8316, {x1 -> 0.971638, y1 -> -1.74839, x2 -> -1.03012,  y2 -> -1.71463}}}`

The result is not so bad as

```
Show[{Region[Disk[]], Region[Disk[{x1, y1}, 1]], 
Region[Disk[{x2, y2}, 1]]} /. {x1 -> 0.9716380122653828, 
y1 -> -1.7483909817229744, x2 -> -1.030124037546774,y2 -> -1.7146315581489628}]
```

[image]
demonstrates.

The problem is that for four disks the code

```
NMinimize[{Evaluate[ Area[ConvexHullRegion[RegionUnion[Disk[], 
Disk[{x1, y1}, 1], Disk[{x2, y2}, 1], Disk[{x3, y3}, 1]]]]], x1^2 + y1^2 >= 4 && x2^2 + y2^2 >= 4 && && x3^2 + y3^2 >= 4, (x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2 >= 4 && (x1 - x3)^2 + (y1 - y3)^2 >= 4 &&(x3 - x2)^2 + (y3 - y2)^2 >= 4}, {x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3}]
```

does not work

> Syntax::sntxf: "{Evaluate[Area[ConvexHullRegion[RegionUnion[Disk[],Disk[{x1,y1},1],
> Disk[{x2,y2},1],Disk[{x3,y3},1]]]]]," cannot be followed by "x1^2+y1^2>=4&&
> x2^2+y2^2>=4&&&&x3^2+y3^2>=4,(x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2>=4&&(x1-x3)^2+(y1-y3)^2>=4&&(x3-x2)^2+(y3-y2)^2>=4}".

How to overcome it? Can some Mathematica code do it for a dozen  unit disks?

Addition. Now I am sure that this issue is a bug in `NMInimize` which badly handles geometric objects. The code works for `n==3`, but produces a syntax error for `n==4`.  Unfortunately, I cannot submit that bug. I tried it several times but I saw only "Server connection is not accessible" (in Russian).

Comment: Same radius and no constraint of disks being inside some boundary or region? Then the solution is know to be [hexagonal packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing) (which you got) and which Lagrange proved in 1773.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov: My question is only related to the densest packing problem. I find a configuration when the area of the convex hull of these disks is smallest. I didn't get any hexagonal packing. BTW, Wiki says "The first rigorous proof is attributed to László Fejes Tóth in 1942.[1][2]", not to Lagrange. Can you pay your attention to my questions "How to overcome it? Can some Mathematica code do it for a dozen unit disks?". Thank you anyway.

Comment: There is no bug. The first warning is due to symbolic evaluation, which you should prevent (for example, with a classical trick `f[x1_?NumericQ, y1_, x2_, ...] := Area[...]; NMinimize[{f[x1, y1, x2, ...}, ...]`). And the second code has a syntactic error, which is mentioned in the warning message. You have four consecutive `&` in the code.

Comment: @Domen: Thank you for your valuable comment. However, `NMinimize[{f[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3], 
  x1^2 + y1^2 >= 4 && x2^2 + y2^2 >= 4 && && 
   x3^2 + y3^2 >= 4, (x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2 >= 
    4 && (x1 - x3)^2 + (y1 - y3)^2 >= 4 && (x3 - x2)^2 + (y3 - y2)^2 >=
     4}, {x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3}]` (in your suggested notation)  crashes my comp.

Comment: Three votes to close the question because  "This question doesn’t meet a Mathematica Stack Exchange guideline" are not understandable (not only to me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- We try to manually construct the convex hull.

```
Clear[dist, r, sol, disks];
dist[p1_, p2_] = Sqrt[(p2 - p1) . (p2 - p1)];
r = 1; sol = 
 NMinimize[{Area[Polygon[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}]] + 
    r*dist[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}] + r*dist[{x2, y2}, {x3, y3}] + 
    r*dist[{x3, y3}, {x1, y1}] + π*r^2, 
   dist[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}]^2 >= (2 r)^2, 
   dist[{x2, y2}, {x3, y3}]^2 >= (2 r)^2, 
   dist[{x3, y3}, {x1, y1}]^2 >= (2 r)^2}, {x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3}]
disks = {Disk[{x1, y1}, r], Disk[{x2, y2}, r], Disk[{x3, y3}, r]} /. 
   sol[[2]];
Graphics[{ConvexHullRegion[RegionUnion@disks], Red, disks}]
```

> `{10.8736, {x1 -> 1.12343, y1 -> -4.20116, x2 -> -0.466292,  y2 -> -2.98757, x3 -> -0.722433, y3 -> -4.9711}}`.

[image]

- For four points `{x4, y4}, {x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}` which construct a convex quadrilateral,we directly construct the convex hull region and calculate its area( the interior convex polygon and four rectangles and four sectors)

```
Clear[dist, r, sol, disks];
dist[p1_, p2_] := Sqrt[(p2 - p1) . (p2 - p1)];
r = 1;
area[pts_] := 
 Area@ConvexHullMesh[pts] + 
  r*ArcLength@RegionBoundary[ConvexHullMesh[pts]] + π*r^2;

sol = NMinimize[{area[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}], 
   dist[{x4, y4}, {x1, y1}]^2 >= (2 r)^2, 
   dist[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}]^2 >= (2 r)^2, 
   dist[{x2, y2}, {x3, y3}]^2 >= (2 r)^2, 
   dist[{x3, y3}, {x4, y4}]^2 >= (2 r)^2, 
   dist[{x4, y4}, {x2, y2}]^2 >= (2 r)^2, 
   dist[{x1, y1}, {x3, y3}]^2 >= (2 r)^2}, {x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, 
   x4, y4}]
disks = {Disk[{x4, y4}, r], Disk[{x1, y1}, r], Disk[{x2, y2}, r], 
    Disk[{x3, y3}, r]} /. sol[[2]];
Graphics[{ConvexHullRegion[RegionUnion@disks], Red, disks}]
```

> `{14.6057, {x1 -> -0.904291, y1 -> 0.864878, x2 -> 0.577155,  y2 -> 2.2085, x3 -> -0.481404, y3 -> -1.0899, x4 -> 1.00004,  y4 -> 0.253719}}`

[image]

### For `n=7`;

```
Clear["Global`*"];
dist[p1_, p2_] := Sqrt[(p2 - p1) . (p2 - p1)];
r = 1;
n = 7;
area[pts_] := 
  Area@ConvexHullMesh[pts] + 
   r*ArcLength@RegionBoundary[ConvexHullMesh[pts]] + π*r^2;
sol = NMinimize[{area[Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 1, n}]], 
    Flatten[Table[
      dist[{x[i], y[i]}, {x[j], y[j]}]^2 >= (2 r)^2, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1,
        i - 1}]]}, Flatten[Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 1, n}]]];
disks = Table[Disk[{x[i], y[i]}, 1], {i, 1, n}] /. sol[[2]];
Graphics[{ConvexHullRegion[RegionUnion@disks], Red, disks}]
```

[image]

- For `n=8`,by using `Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"` we get

[image]

- For `n=9`.

[image]

- For `n=10`, by using `Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"` we get

[image]

- To avoid the warning message,we use `?RegionQ` and `FindInstance` to set `"InitialPoints"`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
dist[p1_, p2_] = Sqrt[(p2 - p1) . (p2 - p1)];
r = 1;
n = 6;
area[reg_?RegionQ] := 
  Area@reg + r*ArcLength@RegionBoundary@reg + π*r^2;
ini = Flatten@Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 1, n}] /. 
   FindInstance[
    Flatten@Table[
      dist[{x[i], y[i]}, {x[j], y[j]}]^2 >= (2 r)^2, {i, 2, n}, {j, 1,
        i - 1}], Flatten[Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 1, n}]], 1];
sol = NMinimize[{area@
     ConvexHullMesh@Point@Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 1, n}], 
    Flatten@Table[
      dist[{x[i], y[i]}, {x[j], y[j]}]^2 >= (2 r)^2, {i, 2, n}, {j, 1,
        i - 1}]}, Flatten@Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 1, n}], 
   Method -> {"Automatic", "InitialPoints" -> ini}];
disks = Table[Disk[{x[i], y[i]}, 1], {i, 1, n}] /. sol[[2]];
Graphics[{ConvexHullRegion[RegionUnion@disks], Red, disks}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Thank you for your interesting approach. I don't understand why `Polygon[{{x4, y4}, {x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}]` is convex. Let us consider `r = 1; x1 = 3; y1 = 4; x2 = 5; y2 = 0; x3 = 7; y3 = 1; Graphics[
 Polygon[{{0, 0}, {x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}]]`. Also how to realize your approach for, say, 7 disks?

Comment: I think `Area[ConvexHullMesh[{{x4, y4}, {x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}]]` instead of `Area[Polygon[{{x4, y4}, {x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}]]` would be better.

Comment: Unfortunately, `sol = NMinimize[{Area[
     ConvexHullMesh[{{x4, y4}, {x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}]] + 
    r*dist[{x4, y4}, {x1, y1}] + r*dist[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}] + 
    r*dist[{x2, y2}, {x3, y3}] + r*dist[{x3, y3}, {x4, y4}] + 
    2 \[Pi]*r^2, dist[{x4, y4}, {x1, y1}]^2 >= (2 r)^2, 
   dist[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}]^2 >= (2 r)^2, 
   dist[{x2, y2}, {x3, y3}]^2 >= (2 r)^2, 
   dist[{x3, y3}, {x4, y4}]^2 >= (2 r)^2, 
   dist[{x4, y4}, {x2, y2}]^2 >= (2 r)^2, 
   dist[{x1, y1}, {x3, y3}]^2 >= (2 r)^2}, {x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, 
   x4, y4}]` results in

Comment: `{20.5469, {19.7473, {x1 -> -1.22724, y1 -> 2.177, x2 -> 0.201918, 
   y2 -> 0.777889, x3 -> -0.295164, y3 -> -1.15935, x4 -> 1.63108, 
   y4 -> -0.621219}}}` which does not seem optimal.

Comment: The `Method->"DifferentialEvolution"` option helps.

Comment: @user64494 The four points case need to be modified later. The minimum should be `dist[p1_, p2_] = Sqrt[(p2 - p1) . (p2 - p1)];
Area[Polygon[{{x4, y4}, {x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}]] + 
  r*dist[{x4, y4}, {x1, y1}] + r*dist[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}] + 
  r*dist[{x2, y2}, {x3, y3}] + 
  r*dist[{x3, y3}, {x4, y4}] + π*r^2 /. {x4 -> 0, y4 -> 0, 
  x1 -> 1, y1 -> -Sqrt[3], x2 -> 2, y2 -> 0, x3 -> 1, y3 -> Sqrt[3], 
  r -> 1}`, that is `8 + 2 Sqrt[3] + π`

Comment: cvgmt (@ does not work.): That's great, but you don't answer my comments.

Comment: cvgmt (@ does not work.): Thank you for your edit. The question remains open: how to realize your approach for, say, 7 disks?

Comment: cvgmt (@ does not work.): Not taking into account several warnings (`NMinimize` does hardly deal with geometric objects.), I accept your good answer.

Comment: The result for $n=8$ is sure unexpected: `{32.2069, {x[1] -> -2.77539, y[1] -> 1.76911, x[2] -> 0.38431, 
  y[2] -> -1.54888, x[3] -> 0.893691, y[3] -> 2.3754, 
  x[4] -> -2.16492, y[4] -> -0.135443, x[5] -> -1.55445, 
  y[5] -> -2.04, x[6] -> -0.820762, y[6] -> 1.34552, 
  x[7] -> -0.159754, y[7] -> -3.47346, x[8] -> 0.928367, 
  y[8] -> 0.375696}}`. See its visualization  by `disks = Table[Disk[{x[i], y[i]}, 1], {i, 1, n}] /. sol[[2]];
Graphics[{ConvexHullRegion[RegionUnion@disks], Red, disks}]`.

Comment: Making use of `Method->"DifferentialEvolution"` option, one obtains an optimal result `{29.5339, {x[1] -> 1.34055, y[1] -> -1.02538, x[2] -> 3.82246, 
  y[2] -> 1.39126, x[3] -> 5.2177, y[3] -> -0.0416765, 
  x[4] -> -0.598029, y[4] -> -1.51723, x[5] -> -1.99327, 
  y[5] -> -0.0842964, x[6] -> 3.27913, y[6] -> -0.533527, 
  x[7] -> -0.0546957, y[7] -> 0.407554, x[8] -> 1.88388, 
  y[8] -> 0.899405}}` for $n=8$.

Comment: @cvgmt: When I run your latest code with `n=6` it finds figure that is not minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Your method would not work because of:

1. `ConvexHullRegion` is imprecise (even `WorkingPrecision` has no effect in `Area`). For example area of union of two half disks that form together whole disk of radius `1`is `π` but the code gives imprecise output `3.12989`.

---

```
Area[ConvexHullRegion[
  RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, π}], 
   Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {π, 2 π}]]]]
Area[ConvexHullRegion[
  RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, π}], 
   Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {π, 2 π}]]], WorkingPrecision -> 100]

(* 3.12989 *)
(* 3.12989 *)
```

---

2. The solution might not be unique. The following shows two versions how to arrange six disks that in both cases we have the same convex hull area - which is obvious since the red disk can be placed in two different places next to five black disks without changing convex hull area.

[image]

**Update**

For those who cannot see that the above figures have the same area... Both figures consist of the same three shapes - red, blue, black. Both have `4` red ones, `6` blues ones and `6` black ones.

[image]

Comment: You open an opened door. Also your claim "The solution might not be unique"  is not grounded at all. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Well, it is pretty obvious that convex hull area in both of my images is the same, thus the solution is not unique.

Comment: Sorry, you don't derive these configurations with Mathematica. Why are  those optimal?

Comment: Of course I did, I will not post code that is trivial enough so that you can do it yourself.

Comment: azerbajdzan (@ does not work.): Sorry I have nothing to discuss with you in such a manner.